# absolute convergence of the Fourier coeff for Hölder continuous function

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I saw the following theorem in the wiki page:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

---

if $f$ satisfies the  $\alpha$-Hölder condition 
$| f(x) - f(y) | \leq C \, |x - y|^{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>1/2$,
then

$||f||_{A} = \sum_i |c_{i}|\leq C c_{\alpha}$

where $c_{\alpha}$ only depends on $\alpha$

---

But I could not find a reference or a proof for this theorem. 
Can anybody provide me a ref for this? Thanks  a lot!

Comment: What is the $A$ norm and what are the $c_i$s? 

Comment: Have you tried Katznelson's book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is outlined in Stein-Shakarchi's book Fourier Analysis, Chapter 3, Exercise 16.